# Delete all rows after N number in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a excel having 100 of sheets. Each sheet is having more than 40K rows. I want to keep just first 20 rows(*or even any 20 rows is fine if first 20 is not possible*) and delete all the remaining rows. How to do this in excel? Is there any formula available. Currently I'm manually selecting and deleting the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a simple loop through your `Worksheets`, and as per your requirement; you can exclude certain sheets by putting them into an array. For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'Exclude these
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Check if ws should be excluded
    With Application
        If .Count(.Match(ws.Name, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
            'Remove data from row 21 onwards
            ws.Range("21:" & ws.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is removing only column A. I have column till G. Should i change to `Range("A21: G") ` ?

Comment: @Omega, `EntireRow` should ensure the whole row gets deleted. It's adjusted now to work in any case.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Range("21:40000").EntireRow.delete
Next ws

End Sub
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I put in 40.000 as  last row but you can just fill that in with a way of getting the actual last row of a ws. I dont have excel here right now so i cant test it. Should be easy to find though.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. How to exclude some sheets?

Comment: With an if clause in the for loop before the command. if you want to filter by name for example you would do if ActiveSheet.Name = 'Sheet 23' Then Next ws

Basically you check for your condition and when it is true than you just use Next ws to go to the next ws without doing anything.